# The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.3

Tags: c#, sql-server

Can someone help me figure out why I am getting this error? I have the same code on my PC and it works fine, but on my friend's laptop it wont work. We have the same SQL Server datetime format. I've already tried to convert the string date format as the same as the SQL Server date format but it still won't work.

EDIT: My bad I posted the wrong code.

```
        DateTime paymentCashDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtPaymentCash.Text).AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
        DateTime orderDate = Convert.ToDateTime(lblDate.Text);

        if (orderDate < paymentCashDate)
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Orders SET PaymentStatus=@PaymentStatus, Status=@Status, PaymentAmount=@PaymentAmount, PaymentDate=@PaymentDate WHERE OrderNo=@OrderNo AND Status='Pending'; " +
            "UPDATE OrderDetails SET Status=@Status WHERE OrderNo=@OrderNo AND Status='Pending';";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Approved");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaymentStatus", "Payment Accepted");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaymentDate", paymentCashDate.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaymentAmount", txtAmountCash.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", orderNo);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            addProject(orderNo);
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            errorPayment.Visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: If it's a datetime in the DB why are you passing a `string`?  Also why are you formatting `DateTime` objects to strings to do a comparison, expecially since you're not using 24 hour time?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: There might be case that you are passing invalid date like '2017-06-31' which will also lead to the same error while converting to datetime.

Comment: @juharr sorry i posted the wrong code, ive updated it now.

Comment: @JdVillar Try removing the `ToString` after `paymentCashDate`.  That will pass it as a datetime and the formatting will be handled for you if the PaymentDate column is a datetime type..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to update a `string`(`nvarchar`) into a datetime Column.
change:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaymentDate", paymentCashDate.ToString());
```

To:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaymentDate", paymentCashDate);
```

Another thing, I see you are using a `TextBox` control to hold the date (its ok because you are casting the text into `DateTime`), but i suggest you To use `DateTimePicker` Control, it will save the need of casting and the user will have a better UX.

[Introduction to the Windows Forms DateTimePicker Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983598(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Yeah this worked! Damn ive been figuring out this for an hour lmao. Btw can i ask, how come this code doesnt have an error in my pc and it has on my friends laptop even though we have the same sql database

Comment: good chance that the format of the the date text on your freind OS is different from your OS 12/12/2012 vs 12-dec-12..

Comment: Also, try as much as you can to avoid converting `Datetime` into `string`
in all parts of your program, there are cases (specially on a large projects) that finding the bug is hard and will waste your time (I have learned it in the past trough the hard way..)